# Grails Quartz job performance degrades / slows over time

Tags: spring, performance, grails, grails-orm, quartz-scheduler

We have a situation where we have a Grails 2.3.11 based application that uses Quartz (version 2.2.1 / Grails Quartz plugin version 1.0.2) jobs to do certain long running processes (1-5 minutes) in background so that a polling service allows the browser to fetch the progress. This is used primarily for import and export of data from the application. For example, when the application first starts, the export for 200,000+ rows takes approx 2 minutes. The following day the export takes 3+ minutes. The third day the export takes more than 6 minutes.

We have narrowed the problem down to just the Quartz jobs. When the system is in the degraded state all other web pages respond with nearly identical response times as when the system is in optimal condition. It appears that the Quartz jobs tend to slowdown linearly or incrementally over the period of 2 to 3 days. This may be usage related or time, for which we are uncertain.

We are familiar with the memory leak bug [reported by Burt Beckwith](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=73) and added the fix to our code. We were experiencing the memory leak before but now memory management appears to be health, even when the job performance is 5-10x slower than

The jobs use GORM for most of the queries. We've optimized some to use criterias with projects so they are light weight but haven't been able to change all the logic over so there are a number of Gorm objects. In the case of the exports we've changed the queries to be read-only. The logic also clears out the hibernate session appropriately to limit the number of objects in memory.

Here are a few additional details:

- The level-2 cache is disabled
- Running on Tomcat 7
- Using MySQL 5.6
- Using Java JDK 1.7.0_72
- Linux
- System I/O, swapping and CPU are all well within reason
- Heap and Permgen memory usage is reasonable
- Garbage collection is stable and reasonably consistent based on usage levels
- The issue occurs even when there is only a single user
- We have done period stack/thread dump analysis
- We have been profiling the application with xRebel (development) and AppDynamics (production) as well we have Java Melody installed into the application
- We had this problem with Grails 1.3.8 but recently upgraded to 2.3.11 which may have exasperated the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Hi John, any solution regarding this? I am encountering this as well.

Comment: Hi,
We experience this as well, any solution ?